# Using HtmlAgilityPack with MonoTouch app gives reference error

Tags: xamarin.ios, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to use the Html Agility Pack with a MonoTouch application, but cannot find a version that will work with it.

I downloaded the latest binaries from [CodePlex](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/90925) and I've tried building with every DLL it contains.  None will compile when the target is the iPhone.

Adding the .NET 20 library will allow it to compile to the iPhone Simulator, but when switching to the iPhone I get the error:

```
Error MT2002: Can not resolve reference: System.Diagnostics.TraceListener (MT2002) (MFLPlatinum12)
```

It seems like others are using HtmlAgilityPack with MonoTouch projects, so any thoughts as to what I'm missing?

Comment: Could you possibly share the MonoTouch library you built for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you compiling from source or using the DLL directly?

You will need to make a new MonoTouch library project and add all the files for it to work.

Using a DLL directly likely won't work, since it was not compiled for MonoTouch.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was using the DLLs.  I'll try that.

Comment: @KenPespisa could you explain how you went about doing this. Im running into the same problem.

Comment: It looks like the question you posted (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449352/compiling-html-agility-pack-for-monotouch?lq=1) gave you the answer.  I did essentially the same thing.  I just created a new project and added all the .cs files, then compiled it and referenced that project in my iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile it from code
Download the source

go into

```
\htmlagilitypack-99964\Branches\1.4.0\HtmlAgilityPack
```

Edit the `csproj` change to

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Novell\Novell.MonoDroid.CSharp.targets" />
```

Save and load

Fix errors

Trace -> Debug

Remove block

```
 if (!SecurityManager.IsGranted(new DnsPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted)))
        {
            //do something.... not at full trust
            try
            {
                RegistryKey reg = Registry.ClassesRoot;
                reg = reg.OpenSubKey(extension, false);
                if (reg != null) contentType = (string)reg.GetValue("", def);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                contentType = def;
            }
        }
```

Remove block

```
 if (SecurityManager.IsGranted(new RegistryPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted)))
        {
            try
            {
                RegistryKey reg = Registry.ClassesRoot;
                reg = reg.OpenSubKey(@"MIME\Database\Content Type\" + contentType, false);
                if (reg != null) ext = (string)reg.GetValue("Extension", def);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ext = def;
            }
        }
```

Use the `dll` in the `bin/debug` folder

Comment: Where are the blocks we need to remove?