# Failed to resolve "Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey" reference from "mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" (MT2002)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

When trying to debug on my iPhone I get the error:

```
Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey" reference from "mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" (MT2002)
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is your code referencing the RegistryKey class or is it referenced from another assembly that you reference? This other assembly will need to be recompiled with monotouch too. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018240/using-htmlagilitypack-with-monotouch-app-gives-reference-error/15471790#15471790

Comment: @PreetSangha Hmm yup I am using HTML agility pack, but I thought I had precompiled it.. Maybe not I dont really understand how to do it

Comment: Follow the instructions in the answer I linked to.

Comment: @PreetSangha They are pretty ambiguous and for android..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is a result of using the type Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey in your project or any third party libraries, this likely not available in MonoTouch

I would take a look at the library you have developed and double check everything is ok.

Comment: Im assuming i need to build the HTML agility pack for montouch. How do I go about doing that?