# Compiling HTML Agility Pack for Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, html-agility-pack, xamarin

I have been pointed to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15471790/1094339) regarding using [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) in Monotouch. However the answer is poorly formatted, ambiguous, and some parts have android mentioned.

I am new to Xamarin could someone please step me through the process of compiling a project for use in Monotouch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to tackle this, but one approach would be

1. create a new iOS Library Project
2. add the *.cs files from HtmlAgilityPack
3. build
4. resolve any build errors
5. goto 3

Comment: +1 as this will work for other libraries and with any version of Xamarin.iOS (either 6.2.x based on the old Silverlight-like profile and the new, 6.3.x beta, based on a .NET 4.5-like profile).

Comment: @Jason which *.cs files are you talking about ?

Comment: all of the *.cs files in the library.  If you're trying to parse HTML in Xamarin, look at the AngleSharp package, it's a easier solution